# Add a border to a table's tr on hover with JQuery?

Tags: jquery, css

Please, is it possible to add a border to a table's tr on hover with JQuery?

I mean,

```
$("#table tr").hover(function()
{
$(this).css("border","1px solid #6da8dc");
$("#doc_options").show();
},function()
{
$(this).css("border","none");
$("#doc_options").hide();
});
```

And if this works, how do I create a 1px invisible border that is set on each tr so that when I hover, the tr doesn't jump because a 1px border has just been added.

Comment: Is there something wrong with `#table tr { border: 1px solid transparent; } #table tr:hover { border: 1px solid #6da8dc; }` ?

Comment: css can do this like david do...

Comment: Do note that you will run into trouble with your tr borders when it comes to IE. Not that anyone should care.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree with @David Dorward, you don't really need jQuery for this. But assuming you want to do something more complicated such as fade in `"#doc_options"`, this should get you started:

http://jsfiddle.net/jm3kY/

```
$("#table tr").hover(function() {
    $(this).addClass('trHover');
    $("#doc_options").show();
}, function() {
    $(this).removeClass('trHover');
    $("#doc_options").hide();
});
```

**CSS:**

```
#doc_options {
    display: none
}
#table tr {
    border: 1px solid transparent
}
#table .trHover {
    border: 1px solid #6da8dc
}
```

Comment: I still have a problem @thirtydot [jsfiddle.net/shoppyonline/QMfCp/7/](http://jsfiddle.net/shoppyonline/QMfCp/7/) The tr .Hover doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @Shoppyonline: On that jsFiddle, you forgot to change the "Framework" option on the left to "jQuery 1.5.1". It will work after you do that.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways:

Use a transparent border as David suggests in his comment

```
$("#table tr").hover(function() {
  $(this).css("border","1px solid #6da8dc");
},function() {
  $(this).css("border","1px solid transparent");
});
```

Set a padding of at least 1px and subtract that 1px when showing the border:

```
$("#table tr").hover(function() {
  $(this).css({"border": "1px solid #6da8dc", "padding: 4px"});
},function() {
  $(this).css({"border": "none", "padding: 5px"};
});
```

Use `outline` instead (unsupported by IE < 8):

```
$("#table tr").hover(function() {
  $(this).css("outline","1px solid #6da8dc");
},function() {
  $(this).css("outline","none");
});
```

EDIT: In all cases it's better to put the styling in the style sheet as thirtydot suggests.

Comment: Yes thats what I did initially. Looks like I'll go back to that. Thanks